# Would a bar chart be a good way to show this type of data?

Tags: barplot

I'm given around 15 data points, which are just numerical values.

The point of the graph is to show that all of these data points are under some maximum threshold. Would a bar chart be a good way to display this, with every bar as a separate data point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your data, but theoretically it would work. It would be even better if you also plot the line of the maximum threshold to make it even clearer.

If you want a more "advanced" visualization, try some of [these](https://gramener.github.io/visual-vocabulary-vega/#/Deviation/) to show deviation from this maximum threshold.